# How to push a requestDto to Redis and have it persisted until it's been read?

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'd like to take a RequestDTO that has been POST'd to a ServiceStack service and push that to Redis with the built in messaging capabilities provided by ServiceStack.Server RedisMqServer. This message should be durable (if it was successfully pushed) in the sense that it should survive reboots of the Redis server (if that were to happen) and other unfortunate events. It should persist until it has been read/processed by another yet to be determined service.

Is this Pub/Sub, Request/Response, or just Request/no Response?

Thank you, Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your Redis Server is configured to persist to disk, the docs on [redis persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) describe how to configure Redis **RDB Snapshots** and support for **Append Only File**.

Important note about Append Only File in Redis:

> The suggested (and default) policy is to **fsync every second**. It is both very fast and pretty safe. The always policy is very slow in practice (although it was improved in Redis 2.0) – there is no way to make fsync faster than it is.

In practice means there is a chance to lose data if redis-server process terminated unexpectedly.

[ServiceStack's Rabbit MQ Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ) provides a more durable option for MQ Services which has true **ACK** support so a message is only removed from the MQ Broker when the client explicitly acknowledges to do so.